# SQLCMD utility from BAT file - how to return ERRORLEVEL in case of syntax error

Tags: sql, batch-file, syntax-error, sqlcmd

How can I get %ERRORLEVEL% from SQLCMD utility when some of .sql files contains syntax error? These files create stored procedures. They don't invoke "raiseerror", but they can conatin syntax error and I need to terminate the process.
But it always returns %ERRORLEVEL% as 0.
I tried use -b, -V and -m (and their combinations), but nothing worked for me as expected.

Here's the code fragment of my BAT file.

```
REM process all sql files in "SQL\scripts" folder and subfolders
FOR /R "SQL\scripts" %%G IN (*.sql) DO (
    sqlcmd -d %1 -S %2 -U %3 -P %4 -i "%%G" -b -V 1

    echo %ERRORLEVEL%
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do need the `-b` switch but together with `enabledelayedexpansion`, that way you can use `!errorlevel!` inside the loop and get the expected results.

Put `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` anywhere before you execute `sqlcmd`, probably best at the beginning of the batch or just before the loop. Also note the use of exclamation points (`!`) instead of the percent signs (`%`), which denote the use of delayed expansion.

[I also tested with `if not errorlevel 0 …` (no `!`, nor any `%`: see `help if`) but I could not get the desired results]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, here is the work batch script.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /R "C:\SQL" %%G IN (*.sql) DO (
sqlcmd -S%1 -d tangoDB -E -h-1 -w255 -i "%%G" -b
echo   %%G  -  !ERRORLEVEL!
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 EXIT /B !ERRORLEVEL!
)
```