# How to set %ERRORLEVEL% in cmd /c?

Tags: powershell, cmd, exit-code, errorlevel, delayedvariableexpansion

I want to be able to set the `%ERRORLEVEL%` environment variable (also referred to as a "*system variable*") to an **arbitrary value** in the beginning of a command prompt script (i.e. `cmd /c`) running in **PowerShell**. Whenever people want to set `%ERRORLEVEL%` [(1)](https://superuser.com/questions/649303/setting-errorlevel-to-0), they do the following:

```
cmd /c "exit /b 3"
cmd /c "echo %ERRORLEVEL%"
```

However, although `%ERRORLEVEL%` is set to `3` when the above is run in the normal Command Prompt, if these exact lines are executed in PowerShell, the exit code environment variable is **not** set to `3` and remains `0`. In addition, you **cannot** do the following:

```
cmd /v:on /c "exit /b 3 & echo !ERRORLEVEL!"
```

The `exit` command breaks completely out of the command execution (i.e. `cmd /c`) and no other command after the `&` is run.

Therefore, I tried executing the following command in PowerShell:

```
cmd /v:on /c "SET %ERRORLEVEL% = 4 & echo !ERRORLEVEL!"
```

The expected output is `4`, but this always outputs `0`. I cannot figure out why I am unable to `SET` the `%ERRORLEVEL%` environment variable. I have used delayed command execution ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318643/getting-the-exit-code-of-an-application-started-with-the-cmd-and-start-comma)), but no amount of fiddling seems to work here.

**Does anyone have any idea of why the command `SET %ERRORLEVEL% = 4` does not work?**

If you are **not** able `SET` environment variables, then how can set `%ERRORLEVEL%` to an arbitrary value in a string of commands separated by an ampersand (`&`) like above?

Comment: `SET %ERRORLEVEL% = 4 & ...` actually sets a variable `0<SPACE>` to a value of `<SPACE>4<SPACE>`. You probably meant `set "errorlevel=4" (Hint: DON'T!)

Comment: @Stephan You need `%` to access an environmental variable. If you say `SET errorlevel = 4` then it will create a variable of the same name as the environmental variable. This will create problems as you will no longer be referring to the environmental variable.

Comment: That's why  said "Hint: DON'T". (Btw. SET errorlevel = 4` creates a variable `%errorlevel %` which doesn't interfere with the system variable `%errorlevel%`, but is probably useless for you)

Comment: @Stephan But this is beside the point. I am trying to set `%ERRORLEVEL%`, the system variable. I am not looking to create a dummy, localized variable of the same name. The above code is just to provide a small example.

Comment: @Stephan Also, adding quotes did not fix the problem: `SET "%ERRORLEVEL%=4"`. If we forget about PowerShell for a second, this still does **not** work in Command Prompt.

Comment: Trust @dbenham: [%ERRORLEVEL% is not a normal environment variable. It is a dynamic pseudo variable that returns the current ERRORLEVEL. If you explicitly define a true environment variable with set ERRORLEVEL=0, then the dynamic nature is destroyed, and %ERRORLEVEL% will forever return the value of your user defined environment variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41251785/3439404)

Comment: Another SO worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892882/set-errorlevel-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: So.. in case you missed it.  Despite all of the "shouldn't do".. NO: `SET %ERRORLEVEL% = 4`  YES: `SET ERRORLEVEL=4`.  After being interpreted.. your line was being read something like "SET 0 = 4" where 0 was the last error level followed by a space.. as in set "0 "=" 4"

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Space or no spaces, it doesn't matter. Also, it is very dangerous to do `SET ERRORLEVEL=4`. So, a strong *NO:* there. You are creating a variable of the same name of the environment. This can lead to bad side affects.

Comment: I am looking into the `SETX /m ...` command. If I use this with `%ERRORLEVEL%`, it worked the first time, but it looks like the environmental variable gets stuck and won't even change anymore even when I run `exit /b 8`.

Comment: Mostly agree @Code_Doggo.. I don't know about "very dangerous".. but sure.. shouldn't do.  He seemed frustrated by not understanding how the variables work.. I was trying to tell him how the line was being interpreted.

Comment: @Stephan, good points, but note that while a custom `ERRORLEVEL` variable doesn't technically _modify_ the automatic _pseudo_ environment variable of the same name, it _shadows_ (effectively overrides) it, so that later code that relies on the dynamic value won't work as expected (`help set` refers to these pseudo environment variables as _dynamic environment variables_, even though they're not technically _environment_ variables).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to store the *eventual* exit code in a `cmd.exe` variable for *later* use with `exit`, **do *not* try to set `ERRORLEVEL`**; instead, **use a custom variable name**; e.g., `ec` (for ***e***xit ***c***ode):

```
# Execute in PowerShell
PS> cmd /v /c 'set "ec=3" & echo ... & exit /b !ec!'; $LASTEXITCODE
...
3
```

**On the `cmd.exe` side:**

- `set "ec=3"` sets variable `ec` to value `3`

  - Enclosing the name-value pair in `"..."` isn't strictly necessary, but clearly delineates the end of the value, and allows use of values with embedded special characters such as `&`.
  - The variable's *value* can later be referenced as `%ec%` (*up-front* expansion) or `!ec!` (*delayed* expansion, if enabled via `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` or via command-line switch `/v` - see `help setlocal`)
- `echo ...` is a sample command representing further commands
- `exit /b !ec!` exits with the value of variable `ec` as the exit code; note how the variable is of necessity referenced as `!ec!` rather than `%ec%`, via *delayed* expansion, because the variable was set *as part of the same statement*.

  - Whether you use `/b` (exit the current batch file only) or not doesn't make a difference here; either way, the `exit` statement in this case determines the *process exit code* of the `cmd` instance.

The commands are *sequenced* (unconditionally executed one after the other), with the `&` operator, as part of a single statement.

**On the PowerShell side:**

- PowerShell's analog to `cmd.exe`'s `&` is `;`, the *statement separator* - it allows you to place multiple statements on a single line.
- **[`$LASTEXITCODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode)** is the automatic PowerShell variable that contains the process exit code of the most recently executed external program, which in this case is `cmd.exe`'s, with value `3`.

---

> Does anyone have any idea why the command `SET %ERRORLEVEL% = 4` does not work?

To summarize the helpful information from the comments on the question:

- Fundamentally, **do no try to set the *dynamic* (pseudo) environment variable `%ERRORLEVEL%`** - it is *automatically* maintained by `cmd.exe` to reflect the most recent command's exit code - see the bottom section.
- **Do not put spaces around `=`** in a `cmd.exe` variable assignment:

  - The space(s) *before* the `=` become *part of the variable name*.
  - The space(s) *after* become *part of the value*.
- **Do not enclose the target variable name in `%...%`** (unless you want to *indirectly* set a variable, via another variable whose *value* contains the name of the variable to assign to).

> `set %ERRORLEVEL% = 4`

With `%ERRORLEVEL%` reflecting `0` at the start of your command sequence, the above assignment creates a variable *literally named* `0`  (that is, the value of `%ERRORLEVEL%` followed by a single space), whose value is  `4` (that is, a single space followed by `4`).

---

#### Variables in `cmd.exe`:

Fundamentally, with the exceptions discussed below, **variables in `cmd.exe` are all *environment variables***.

Unlike in shells such as Bash and PowerShell, there is *no* separate namespace for *shell-local* variables that are *not* seen by child processes.

This has the following implications:

- Predefined persistent environment variables such as `%Path%` share the same namespace as custom variables you define with the `SET` command, so you have to be mindful of name collisions.
- Similarly, *child* processes you run from your `cmd.exe` session / batch file *inherit* custom variables you've created in the session.

  - Note that the use of `setlocal` does *not* change that; `setlocal` is a `cmd`-internal scoping mechanism that allows you to *control the lifetime* of custom environment variables, by localizing them to the scope (batch file) in which `setlocal` was called, and removing them via a subsequent `endlocal` call or, implicitly, at the end of the enclosing batch file.

**Custom variables are process-only environment variables** that go out of scope with the `cmd.exe` process; *persistent* environment variable definitions must be created and modified via the *registry*, such as with the `setx.exe` utility.

In addition to the predefined (persistent) environment variables and custom (session-only) environment variables, **`cmd.exe` maintains *dynamic* pseudo environment variables such as `%ERRORLEVEL%` and `%RANDOM%`** (see list below):

- These pseudo environment variables have *dynamic* values maintained by `cmd.exe` itself...
- ... and they are *not* visible to child processes.

Note: Strictly speaking, these dynamic variables are only enabled with the so-called command extensions turned on, but that is true *by default* (you can disable them with `/E:OFF`, but that is ill-advised).

Because these dynamic variables are not strictly part of the *process environment* that child processes inherit a copy of, they are not *environment* variables, even though **`help SET` somewhat confusingly calls them *dynamic environment variables***.

**You shouldn't (and cannot) modify these variables.**

If you try, what really happens is that you *shadow* (override) these pseudo variables with *real*, custom environment variables, which by definition have *static* values.

Later code that relies on the variables by that name to have their usual, dynamic behavior can therefore malfunction.

**The list of dynamic variables**, as retrieved on Windows 10 via `help SET` (emphasis added):

> If **Command Extensions are enabled**, then there are **several dynamic
>   environment variables** that can be expanded but which **don't show up in
>   the list of variables displayed by `SET`**.  These variable values are
>   **computed dynamically** each time the value of the variable is expanded.
>   **If the user explicitly defines a variable with one of these names, then
>   that definition will override** the dynamic one described below:
>
> - `%CD%` - expands to the current directory string.
> - `%DATE%` - expands to current date using same format as DATE command.
> - `%TIME%` - expands to current time using same format as TIME command.
> - `%RANDOM%` - expands to a random decimal number between 0 and 32767.
> - `%ERRORLEVEL%` - expands to the current ERRORLEVEL value
> - `%CMDEXTVERSION%` - expands to the current Command Processor Extensions
>     version number.
> - `%CMDCMDLINE%` - expands to the original command line that invoked the
>     Command Processor.
> - `%HIGHESTNUMANODENUMBER%` - expands to the highest NUMA node number
>     on this machine.